# Bash Script + Shift Multiple Variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shift

I have created a simple bash script on Linux to create random files. I pass the filenames and filesize to the script like this:

```
./createFiles 5 filename1 filename2
```

*5 = filesize

My code looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

oriDir=files/ori
fileSize=$1
fileName=$2


# Create files
for fileName do

    dd if=/dev/urandom of=$oriDir/$2.mp4 bs=1048576 count=$fileSize

    # Shift through filenames
    shift 1

done
```

The output is as expected. 2 new files in my dir:

```
filename1.mp4 (size 5)
filename2.mp4 (size 5)
```

What I would to to do now is to use various filesizes foreach filename. My command would than look something like this:

```
./createFiles 5 2 filename1 filename2
```

The script would than generate 2 files:

```
filename1.mp4 (size 5)
filename2.mp4 (size 2)
```

Optionally, the script should be able to do the following: in case there are more filenames than given filesizes, it should just take the last filesize for all remaining filenames:

```
./createFiles 5 2 filename1 filename2 filename3
```

would generate:

```
filename1.mp4 (size 5)
filename2.mp4 (size 2)
filename3.mp4 (size 2)
```

I did try to play around with shift and add another shit command, but nothing worked.

Comment: The way you've chosen to structure the arguments <size>... <file>... doesn't lend itself to simple shell programming. Try using <size> <file> <size> <file>... instead.

Comment: Your original script is very strange.  It would be more typical to take the shift out of the loop and do: fileSize=$1; shift; for fileName; do dd if=/dev/urandom of=$oriDir/$fileName.mp4 bs=1048576 count=$fileSize; done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you choose something like this

./script file1 size1 file2 size2 ... fileN sizeN

you can iterate over the this list in pairs

```
limit=$[ $#/2 ]; 
for((i=0;i<$limit;i++)){
file=$1 
size=$2

# do some stuff
shift 2
}
```

Comment: remove the do. there is no longer necessary if you use for(()) {} construction in Bash

Comment: Just one last thing: say I have 5 files from which 4 should have the same size. Do I have to add filsize for each file like `file1 size1 file2 size2 ...` or is there a simple way to tell the script `use size1 for file1 ; from file2 to file5 use size2` ? that would just be optional, if its getting too complex I rather not do it.

Comment: the only difference between a filesize and filename is the expression, like filesize is only a number?

Comment: Ya it is. But never mind, I think I have figured something out that does what I intended :) Thanks for all your help!